# How to prevent the monitor from turning off in Linux

Tags: linux, display, xorg, power-management

I have to start a QT-Program on the screen on startup in Linux Mint 9. 
The monitor that is displaying the program turns off after an unknown amount of time. 
I already deactivated the turnoff in the systemconfiguration,
but it doesn't seem to work.

Hardware specs:

- CPU: Intel ATOM 330
- GPU: Nvidia ION (330)
- 2 GB RAM
- OS: Linux Mint 9

I can't change the OS and the other specs. 
What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 22):

try:

```
xset -dpms
xset s noblank
xset s off
```

Comment: i'll try your line as soon as I'm at work on monday, I'll reply back, thanks in advance :)

Comment: @Linuxnewb What was the result?

Answer (score 10):

Issuing those three commands separately is unnecessary,
according to [Display Power Management Signaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling) at ArchWiki. 
All you need is

```
xset s off -dpms
```

and all you want will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://www.randombugs.com/linux/disable-monitor-standby-xorg-xserver.html) can help you.

In short:

```
xset -dpms
```

Comment: your link has rotten

Comment: @scrat.squirrel you could've proposed a change instead of downvoting. This answer is like 12 years ago, and _sorry_ if I don't get notified whenever one of _my links_ get rotten...

Comment: sure, the answer in 2023 is: `xdg-screensaver` command.

Answer (score 1):

Open the **Power Manager**.  Select the **Display** tab.  On the left where is says "Blank after", move the slider all the way to the left under Plugged In, or the corresponding power type, batter or plugged in.  This is assuming it's not the screen saver that is making your monitor go blank.

This is for Linux Mint 17.2, so I'm not sure if it will be the exact same with your older version.

Comment: `xset -dpms` returns `server has no extension for -dpms option` for me but this works and is way simpler, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in my setup i could do this within my window manager xfce4
'xfce4-power-manager-settings'

Answer (score -2):

The winning combination:

```
xset s noblank dpms force on
```